I wish to code swap features into a telegram wallet. Should I use spl-token-swap AMM
I'm fairly new to solana, and want to get my feet wet. I have a telegram bot which does the very basics: send, receive and show balance and want to add swap functionality.
I had looked at working with the Kraken API, but the problem there is that Kraken is a centralized site which uses a the key specific to MY account. I'd prefer to keep things as decentralized as possible and was looking for solana code for swap, making it independent. I'm going through the the spl-token-swap package (https://github.com/solana-developers) which seems to be most like what I am looking for. As far as I can tell, it basically creates an AMM, which I guess makes sense if I want decentralized. The pools have to be, well... decentralized.
A doubt I have though is that I ran across another solana source (https://spl.solana.com/token-swap)  that indicated "While third-party deployments of token-swap exist on Mainnet Beta, the team has no plans to deploy it themselves."
Can someone refer me to the source of the solana code for SPL tokens on mainnet-beta if it exist?
